# What does this SQL statement mean in plain english... select * from users where user_name like '%' || :user_name || '%' and state_name = 'CA'

Tags: sql

I have some SQL code,

`select * from users where user_name like '%' || :user_name || '%' and state_name = 'CA'`

and a comment that says,

`//find all users who has a name that begins with the same letter as a user who lives in California.`

Is this a valid SQL select statement to find all users who have a name beginnning with the same letter as a different user who lives in california?
I have already looked up the || and : operators, but they seemed to hint that using || is not the proper way to do this type of lookup.

Comment: `||` means concatenation. `'a' || 'b'` => `'ab'`.

Comment: `:user_name` is a host variable/parameter named user_name.

Comment: However, the comment does not describe the query correctly.

Comment: `:user_name` is a variable. So f.e. if it's 'anna' then it becomes `... where user_name like '%anna%'`   It'll match names that contain 'anna'.  Joanna, Hannaka,... The comment is slightly wrong.

Comment: @LukStorms @jarlh So then it should be `...where user_name like LEFT(:user_name,1) || '%' ...`   thanks for the help

Comment: Do you want a query doing what the comment says - or do you want to know what the given query returns?

Comment: @jarlh i would like to know the proper way to do the query in the comment ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select * from users where user_name like '%' || :user_name || '%' and state_name = 'CA'` is not the proper syntax as it would match only users whose names are part of a different user's name

In order to select from a table twice, a join statement must be made.
Also, SUBSTRING must be used to target just the first letter

`select SUBSTRING(users.user_name,1,1) as NAMESTR,users.state,users.user_name,users2.user_name,users2.state from users  INNER join users as users2 on users.state = 'CA' and users2.user_name like NAMESTR || '%'`

The query in the OP was missing a lot of parts.